# Typescript, how to get separated types from an object of objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have object:

```
const themes = {
  light: {
    a...
    b...
  },
  dark: {
    a...
    b...
    c...
    d...
  },
```

The react component takes a `colors` prop that was provided as one of the themes from the object above, which contains in different theme different collection of inner `key: value` entries.
So in my component i access `colors.d`, for example, but TS argues that type, whatever i tried to give him, are wrong.

What have i tried:

1. Didn't work at all, TS says `Property 'd' does not exist on type { a, b, ... }`

```
export type TThemes = typeof themes['light'] | typeof themes['dark'] | (...some more of them)
```

*But when i export only one `typeof`, which i use exactly in react-component - it works, but i need to take care of all themes.*

2. Tried this, TS says just `Property 'd' does not exist on type 'TThemes'`
   :

```
{ [K in keyof typeof themes]: typeof themes[K] }
```

So what should i do to let `colors.d` work normal, when themes might be different inside, but types need to be like `[{...}, {...}, ...]` (*which TS again doesn't like*) ?

**UPD**: The valid version of themes code:

```js
const themes = {
    bordered: {
        background: COLORS.BgMain,
        borderWidth: '1px',
        radius: '4px',
        padding: '20px',
        mobilePadding: '15px',
        color: COLORS.TextPrimary
    },
    simple: {
        background: 'transparent',
        borderWidth: '1px 0',
        radius: '0px',
        padding: '20px 0',
        mobilePadding: '15px 0',
        color: COLORS.TextPrimary
    },
    light: {
        border: COLORS.BgLight,
        background: COLORS.BgLight,
        color: COLORS.TextPrimary,
        colorArrow: COLORS.GRAY_DARK,
        backgroundIcon: COLORS.BgSecondary,
        borderIcon: COLORS.BgSecondary,
        colorArrowIsOpen: COLORS.GRAY_DARK,
        backgroundIconIsOpen: COLORS.Outline_Light,
        borderIconIsOpen: COLORS.Outline_Light,
        radius: BorderRadius.componentRadius,
        padding: '20px 24px',
        mobilePadding: '15px',
        storyColor: COLORS.BgMain,
    },
    dark: {
        border: COLORS.Control,
        background: COLORS.Control,
        color: COLORS.TextWhite,
        colorArrow: COLORS.Control,
        backgroundIcon: COLORS.GRAY_DARK,
        borderIcon: COLORS.GRAY_DARK,
        colorArrowIsOpen: COLORS.Control,
        backgroundIconIsOpen: COLORS.TextWhite,
        borderIconIsOpen: COLORS.TextWhite,
        radius: BorderRadius.componentRadius,
        padding: '20px 24px',
        mobilePadding: '15px',
        storyColor: '#3D3D3D',
    },
};
```

Comment: can you include valid version of `themes`?

Comment: @wonderflame yes, sure, one minute...

Comment: Thanks, and could you include a small portion of the result type that you want to achieve based on the `themes`?

Comment: @wonderflame, I expect it to work first of all) so it should be as i wrote in description: `typeof themes['dark'] OR typeof themes['bordered'] OR ...others...`, so the `colors.accesser` would find his type in a sequence.

Comment: @wonderflame, i found the answer. It should be `typeof themes['dark'] & typeof...` instead of `|`, because as i guess, not sure enough, TS wants here a whole composition and intersection...

Comment: But how to do it without going trough every inner object accessing it for `typeof` i don't know still, better here would be some sort of generic

Comment: And one thing more, with my founded approach it still triggers an error in the parent component, when it says:

`Types of property 'storyColor' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'COLORS'`.
Because after doing `&` i have now `COLORS` enum for storyColor prop in one theme, and a `string` for this prop in another theme.

Comment: Usually you should try to `type` data first instead of assigning unstructured values and building a complex type from that chunk. I suggest defining something like a `Theme` type which forces a theme to have certain properties.

Comment: Situation is that i'm rewriting now old .js file to .ts and need types here.
And how would you first type it when it's just data structured objects with strings, no complex harsh, chunk as you sad. So now point became to type it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the union of properties from all subobjects.  (Pleae correct me if I am wrong).

First make your themes object constant by appending `as const`:

```
const themes = {
  ...
} as const;
```

Then you can get either the intersection of all properties (narrow):

```
type CommonObjectNarrow = typeof themes["bordered"] | typeof themes["simple"] | typeof themes["dark"] | typeof themes["light"];
type CommonPropsNarrow = keyof CommonObjectNarrow; 
// "background" | "radius" | "padding" | "mobilePadding" | "color"
```

or the union of all properties (wide):

```
type ThemeKeys = keyof typeof themes;
type Props<K extends ThemeKeys> = (keyof typeof themes[K]);
type CommonPropsWide = Props<"bordered"> | Props<"simple"> | Props<"dark"> | Props<"light">;
// "background" | "borderWidth" | "radius" | "padding" | "mobilePadding" | "color" 
// | "border" | "colorArrow" | "backgroundIcon" | "borderIcon" | "colorArrowIsOpen" 
// | "backgroundIconIsOpen" | "borderIconIsOpen" | "storyColor"
type CommonObjectWide = {
  [k in CommonPropsWide]: string;
}
```

Here is what in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gYQPIBlcAlAZQC4BveAbQA8zMYBLFAcwF0z5GXWBfANwAoUJFgJk6LACEkMUDCJRgTAK5ouVZAFsADqhAoMSleq482goUMmZ4GABYhtINPAC88CkPi-4AIzkFEGBNHz8I-ygwAGtWGCRVFFCcAmISADppVgBZKBYAGnCI30D5EBgAdSZgRy4AcgBGXVp6opK-GGU1DXh6gBYWtuKS3WUVNgaAJgAGIfaO+G0kfyYIEAAFcd4GxoBWeZGI5Ag5LjxCUgyAFRBaDA3mbVgATxG+Bd80Jj11sMWAtE4gkkil6hguugxnAjMMAWUFNVag5di14DM4YsuqZevU5q1PqNtpM+rM0RjCRFlqt1ltgBNWLsDrR0ZiOiczqlLplbvdHj9Xu9CRAmKwHBh-osERVzmkrtl8KLxZS-FFYvFEslZdysqxFWKMCrfByYNr0jc7g8nq8jYgkKcYABBGAJADuZquAHEiI6AJoAfQAIo6iABpW1q4Ga4AASUkHsy2RI4FQwBtR1VQQqcdQCd1yckaZgL1tJudbpjaFwukMee9fqDIfDGdKQI1oJzKEr1drXPNuFUGBFKBA-v1ypbASzME73ZrKDzA6HLFH48Nk+xPS4snKim66gyOn0I6MJh6trG9J2pPx8CmgwJk+pa02xMZfX2hwBmDkL2w9s5C5zWyPJCiFEYixiSUOmlU0+yuf8jASCAIzbEEtXgzJEIhe1SwAuCgKuXkMEqBwmAwEA8IdcskHdTCMmw5DUPVdDY3jej6wDYMwwjadOzrH0uKbKi5Bo10517QisNQHCUMnSN22SWcq3nPNiNI8jKPkvjJAkhd6PUsiKNtTczHgHcFDPA8jwMU99zQC832mW97y-RZn1pJyP2ZNkSh-Yt-wdBoAGIAGZA3C8LfI+IQrGsDAXhrHAkG0ZYUFwfwACtwAwAA5WA3Q8exEpAJAADN7CcFw0GoAAiWCQlq9h4AAH2Kmtysq5xXDq75fhAJrWva0qKscbqatqyDBrahKOtGqqetqkUDSa4RZoQf9UtQR4kF0NB8pdWiipiEAXk6za0oy7KwDygraIEeAAHpHvgeq0OjWqhtq0y0E+trasvBk-tejzXyvNhgdqk1ausIR1vga4FtDU63E8E6ztGkrOrG6q1pK+Adr2gAeUN4EtQxgDcRHuuRl40AAPiKgAKdHsax+bxuoUN2AASjxpKLu2hI9qRBBPEJtAifq6dGsZtqJalvrdHWWq5YJ4XJcm2AYlVoaFaWpUMFV4RntehTWMh2CkUcSGfshwHeEh0G6SBr7ofgIRTf+2DIbLQ7XUt96O0kS2dNQX38LEvTPs9l7vaDpTdJUwxQ93ZSexQSH-L-fCYfhwX0qynLRaK7xfGoGJ4BYZKtpQCXRc4bgIV4YQ+Fh2GgA) to confirm it:

```
declare const COLORS:{ [x:string]: string};
declare const BorderRadius: { componentRadius: string};

const themes = {
    bordered: {
        background: COLORS.BgMain,
        borderWidth: '1px',
        radius: '4px',
        padding: '20px',
        mobilePadding: '15px',
        color: COLORS.TextPrimary
    },
    simple: {
        background: 'transparent',
        borderWidth: '1px 0',
        radius: '0px',
        padding: '20px 0',
        mobilePadding: '15px 0',
        color: COLORS.TextPrimary
    },
    light: {
        border: COLORS.BgLight,
        background: COLORS.BgLight,
        color: COLORS.TextPrimary,
        colorArrow: COLORS.GRAY_DARK,
        backgroundIcon: COLORS.BgSecondary,
        borderIcon: COLORS.BgSecondary,
        colorArrowIsOpen: COLORS.GRAY_DARK,
        backgroundIconIsOpen: COLORS.Outline_Light,
        borderIconIsOpen: COLORS.Outline_Light,
        radius: BorderRadius.componentRadius,
        padding: '20px 24px',
        mobilePadding: '15px',
        storyColor: COLORS.BgMain,
    },
    dark: {
        border: COLORS.Control,
        background: COLORS.Control,
        color: COLORS.TextWhite,
        colorArrow: COLORS.Control,
        backgroundIcon: COLORS.GRAY_DARK,
        borderIcon: COLORS.GRAY_DARK,
        colorArrowIsOpen: COLORS.Control,
        backgroundIconIsOpen: COLORS.TextWhite,
        borderIconIsOpen: COLORS.TextWhite,
        radius: BorderRadius.componentRadius,
        padding: '20px 24px',
        mobilePadding: '15px',
        storyColor: '#3D3D3D',
    },
};


type CommonObjectNarrow = typeof themes["bordered"] | typeof themes["simple"] | typeof themes["dark"] | typeof themes["light"];
type CommonPropsNarrow = keyof CommonObjectNarrow; // "background" | "radius" | "padding" | "mobilePadding" | "color"


type ThemeKeys = keyof typeof themes;
type Props<K extends ThemeKeys> = (keyof typeof themes[K]);
type CommonPropsWide = Props<"bordered"> | Props<"simple"> | Props<"dark"> | Props<"light">;
// "background" | "borderWidth" | "radius" | "padding" | "mobilePadding" | "color" 
// | "border" | "colorArrow" | "backgroundIcon" | "borderIcon" | "colorArrowIsOpen" 
// | "backgroundIconIsOpen" | "borderIconIsOpen" | "storyColor"
type CommonObjectWide = {
  [k in CommonPropsWide]: string;
}
```

### Update

In response to OP's comment:

```
declare enum COLORS { 
    TextPrimary = "#1",
    BgMain = "#1",
    BgLight = "#2",
    GRAY_DARK = "#3",
    BgSecondary = "#4",
    Outline_Light = "#5",
    Control = "#6",
    TextWhite = "#7"
};
declare const BorderRadius: { componentRadius: "5pix 0"};

const themes = {
    bordered: {
        background: COLORS.BgMain,
        borderWidth: '1px',
        radius: '4px',
        padding: '20px',
        mobilePadding: '15px',
        color: COLORS.TextPrimary
    },
    simple: {
        background: 'transparent',
        borderWidth: '1px 0',
        radius: '0px',
        padding: '20px 0',
        mobilePadding: '15px 0',
        color: COLORS.TextPrimary
    },
    light: {
        border: COLORS.BgLight,
        background: COLORS.BgLight,
        color: COLORS.TextPrimary,
        colorArrow: COLORS.GRAY_DARK,
        backgroundIcon: COLORS.BgSecondary,
        borderIcon: COLORS.BgSecondary,
        colorArrowIsOpen: COLORS.GRAY_DARK,
        backgroundIconIsOpen: COLORS.Outline_Light,
        borderIconIsOpen: COLORS.Outline_Light,
        radius: BorderRadius.componentRadius,
        padding: '20px 24px',
        mobilePadding: '15px',
        storyColor: COLORS.BgMain,
    },
    dark: {
        border: COLORS.Control,
        background: COLORS.Control,
        color: COLORS.TextWhite,
        colorArrow: COLORS.Control,
        backgroundIcon: COLORS.GRAY_DARK,
        borderIcon: COLORS.GRAY_DARK,
        colorArrowIsOpen: COLORS.Control,
        backgroundIconIsOpen: COLORS.TextWhite,
        borderIconIsOpen: COLORS.TextWhite,
        radius: BorderRadius.componentRadius,
        padding: '20px 24px',
        mobilePadding: '15px',
        storyColor: '#3D3D3D',
    },
};

type ThemeKeys = keyof typeof themes;
type Theme<K extends ThemeKeys> = typeof themes[K];
type Props<K extends ThemeKeys> = (keyof typeof themes[K]);
type CommonPropsWide = Props<"bordered"> | Props<"simple"> | Props<"dark"> | Props<"light">;

type KeyTypes1<k extends string, themeKeys extends ThemeKeys[] = ["bordered","simple","dark","light"], t extends any = never> = 
  themeKeys extends [infer HEAD, ... infer TAIL] ?  
  TAIL extends ThemeKeys[] ?
  HEAD extends ThemeKeys ?
  (k extends keyof Theme<HEAD> ? KeyTypes1<k,TAIL,Theme<HEAD>[k] | t> : KeyTypes1<k,TAIL,t>)
    : never : never : t;

type CommonObjectWide = Partial<{
  [k in CommonPropsWide]: KeyTypes1<k>
}>

const obj1: CommonObjectWide = {
    color: COLORS.BgSecondary,
    background: "", //COLORS.BgMain
    radius: BorderRadius.componentRadius, // ""
}

const obj2: CommonObjectWide = {
    color: "", // COLORS.BgSecondary,  error, must be color
    background: COLORS.BgMain,
    radius: "5pix 0"
}
```

Shown in [TypeScript PLayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEIB2BXAtvAwgeQDLYCUBleAb3gCh5r4AVEADwBcAFGASzVgE94BeeACIAxAEZBAGio0AQgHMAslHZJ+QsZOnV5udnIAWTNSIBMmmvADiBAIIBNAPoARGwQDSx4QGZzsuUXAAeyRgHk8AFl9qbBQmCBUQB10DIwERAFYorGCmGECITwA2LPpmAHV9diYENOEAdkEKAF8AbgpQSFgEMGCAZyMZQJhQGAIoYHYUXoAuMngetAAHYOQmMYmp2cF0xfYGeAAGQVaKCh6kfvgmfRA0EF61Ui14ACMhkZBgWaeLCxeoMAAazkeRQIVmOHwxAAdPIlCopL8aG9hiAYGV2MBrrMAOSiRYMHGIpHwGDjSYzeA48IEonPCyLcYTJByXEmA604lItCBF7sCAgFhMlSsqmiHaErm-HoQIYQvCEIjQ0qsDhcGDcZ5NKW9TiLAXfenIgHA0Hgqm5KAXRlwJBMOkk17vNEYrH6XH4-YHB0kskbSk4jmSo3URnAZminHsgmHH3c3n8wXClkeiWxqUWGVyrAKmEqticHhaqXxFKGx0okbyqFKnR6QwZ41AkGBMFfHM12FyZINkPzfLZyGK5WMVWFjWN6hZmA2GB5ADu1eH1nszlcbknrxNLbbAElzkuYfIAudQhO+5W0fvgofa-4giEeJvp7OF7vethFshb9CV44XO4m7-M2ZrANeSDvp+34dsOMRxAkST1kwQHOjA4GQV+SA-nB8RIIkPbIX2foUrMgyoqM5JTNCCzLHhdrrBSm5hhGbJBvAJg0sGjo8nyApCuGIqppyfb9EM3CYAOMA-nCyhIFK2rPGegLliSl5STBMISXaeQQEB26gT+Wm5Pkz6ST+KoVFUICmbKM5zoEi4aUqRk6XpIGtiE4E-n+a6AReqFeU5v62P+642UMr4ORh0FDppOSuRe+keWB5zRVhQUWZU1QoeR6Efph5mjpZ2VEZRlJkSMDFUTRKz0WVTHJpG0b7BxwncQmfGNUJXEkqJGoSbZuLeE4XgjU4cbwApJwUEw3BfnQNx3G4IDcA8AiAitgQAGZXHNIDbVci33G0s3zbQR0ADweKOyDAA8523CAy2rQAfGop37Tt1yPb0ADabgALonXt8BsIEiy9FdiDMLd91Hc9vRvQIAAUG3cAdH0Y0df2AwAlMD80SWgPJIGDEOujUoN5BDF2CGpnyCG9AA+VPg5Dgi6ksAqM-ALNk+zSk83z1Ps6WhiM20M0g89tB7b0ogXYC0PVCEDz9BwLISIdj0I8rsMLTrK1-QDai-XTqEMxIHN6tzVuC1bYtMIIANa0YN2q-AVq8AIeEAG5okjlDUN9S1G3rHu-SoW1ovAAASACiNhOFr0Kp-AUcx7QNi7rgJsAPzUNIWc5+Hd0G6Hq2-fn0gJ0npdw4bq3wHn0io-X8BowdD13BdtdOG9Bcy3LCuAhIxe4GPl19y9v2AibLNMG9sxD1+8uK2P2cT4vuPPLMfsx3vID+zA8CzEwksfdkxPBNgLwAFbgEwFNqEKMBMOwUAQBdPzwLP6eqETEm-MKYA2XitWWq8R4vWaNAs4fQjC8jvqICEgRr5IFvg-MAT9MSUx-lOMyQVjwPjPNwKUwFTTJS2JIeAAB6GhsU7zwiQM8Yimx4AVTRFVXo1FUG0VWFwrWdChCNCaKcc4lxEEmBQWgjBj9n4CDwf2QawjBE0MIfeU8T5qBojyDALWaAphGBeN0SSzxyE7nNAwrsTCpSsMpNsXYXoRGnCAA).

Comment: Thank you, that's very nice, i'd use ThemeKeys + Pops + CommonObjectWide, but here's tiny little thing i need too, that is - most of result of CommonObjectWide fields are of values typef of COLORS, can i in some way shorten result for that amount of types to be specific with them, and only `padding, mobilePadding, storyColor, radius` fields would be of another types: `string,{ componentRadius: string}` ?

Comment: Hi @Gadzhiev Islam. I updated in response to your comment.

Comment: Hi @Craig Hicks, thnx, will take a look